# Search Web Page Content

Tags: ruby

How do you search the Web Page Source in ruby
Hard to explain, but heres a the code for doing it in Python

```
import urllib2, re
word = "How to ask"
source = urllib2.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com").read()
if re.search(word,source):
     print "Found it "+word
```

Answer (score 2):

Directly porting your code:

```
require 'net/http'
word = 'How to ask'
source = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://stackoverflow.com/'))
if source.match(word)
    puts "Found #{word}"
end
```

If you want to do things like follow redirects, you'll want to [read the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html).