# Search Websites Content

Tags: ruby

How do you search a Websites source code with ruby, hard to explain but heres the code for doing it in python

```
import urllib2, re
word = "How to ask"
source = urllib2.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com").read()
if re.search(word,source):
     print "Found it "+word
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate of <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524229/search-web-page-content>; the code is exactly the same.  That user's name was "PHP", this user's name is "python". What's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
require 'open-uri'
word = "How to ask"
open('http://stackoverflow.com') do |f|
  puts "Found it #{word}" if f.read =~ /#{word}/
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is search jcrossley3 gave you your answere. If you want to do something more complicated you should look at an HTML parser that can let you treat the website like a DOM Tree. Have a look at why´s great [hpricot gem](http://wiki.github.com/why/hpricot) to do just that.

```
 require 'hpricot'
 require 'open-uri'
 doc = open("http://qwantz.com/") { |f| Hpricot(f) }
 doc.search("//p[@class='posted']")
 (doc/"p/a/img").each do |img|
   puts img.attributes['class']
 end
```